# Maven plugin in Eclipse can't find hibernate version over 3.6.0

Tags: hibernate, maven

When I try to find hibernate 4.1.0 with eclipse pom editor, I can only find version 3.6.0, I am looking >4.0.0.

Hire is my pom.xml file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>dk.janth.simpel-maven-spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Simpel-maven-spring-projekt</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Simpel maven spring projekt</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as dependency and you should be good to go.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is not always reliable when it comes to find the latest version for an artifact, but I think, in your case, you look for the wrong artifactId.

Most artifacts can be found on maven central, where you we can search and get the xml fragment to add a dependency.

For hibernate: visit [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/), enter "hibernate-core" (not: hibernate) and do a search. At the moment I'm writing that answer, the top result is [hibernate-core, Version 4.2.0.Final](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C4.2.0.Final%7Cjar). Click on that version number (or the link here in this answer, which is the same) and you'll find a page with all dependency information ready to be copied and pasted into your pom.

Comment: Tanks for an good answer. I will use your advise the next time I need at other dependency.